# HTML JQuery Display Array Data in Scroll Box Bullet Points

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have an array of Names `["John", "Jack", "Jill",...]` and I want to display them in an HTML/Jquery text box which is scrollable. i.e.

- John
- Jack
- Jill
  ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a `<ul>`:

```
<ul id="stuff"></ul>
```

Style it so it's scrollable:

```css
#stuff {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Put the items in:

```
var items = ["John", "Jack", "Jill", "James", "Jacqueline", "Jordan", "Joel", "Jay", "Jim"];

$.each(items, function() {
    $('#stuff').append($('<li>').text(this));
});​
```

[And here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/9auSD/)